# Credit Card Processing Fee Field

Tags: civicontribute

I have a volunteer project I am doing and the organization it is for wants to be able to show donors the estimated cost of their credit card processing and then let them add it to their total.  I know we can do this an extension but I am trying to come up with another way. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tuck these into a priceset; so two fields: donation and processing cost; then add some Javascript to the contribution page to do the math and dynamically populate the processing field based on the value in the donation field.

Add another field to the contribution form via a profile (yes/no radio button) and use that in your Javascript as a switch ($0 or do the processing cost calculation).

Comment: I was hoping to find a pre-existing solution but I think this will be the best way.  Thanks Karin!